# Using python lxlm to Parse multiple xml files in multiple subdirectories

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I do have multiple large xml files in multiple subdirectories. I'm trying to sort out the uuids in all the xml files.

**Here is the uuid.xslt file**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="uuids">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="uuid">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="groups">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="groupUuid">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="history">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="historyInfo">
            <xsl:sort select="@versionUuid"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Here is the python code** for that, I can print all the .xml files in all directories & subdirectories, and parse them. I need to create the same dir structure to the new output path

```
iimport os
import lxml.etree as ET

inputpath = "C:\\projects\\test\\uuid\\"
xsltfile = "C:\\projects\\test\\uuid\\uuid.xslt"
outpath = "C:\\projects\\test\\output"

dir = []

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
    structure = os.path.join(outpath, dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    if not os.path.isdir(structure):
        os.mkdir(structure)
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(('.xml')):
            dir = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            print(dir)
            dom = ET.parse(dir)
            xslt = ET.parse(xsltfile)
            transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
            newdom = transform(dom)
            outfile = open(outpath + "\\" + filename, 'a')
            outfile.write(ET.tostring(newdom,pretty_print=True).decode())
```

I'm seeing few issues in the output

1. destination output files should be stored in the same dir structure as source. I'm able to create the same dir structure, but I'm not able to pass the files to same dir's, all files are stored at root location only.

for example:
source:

C:\projects\xmlformat\uuid\new.xml
C:\projects\xmlformat\uuid\patches.xml
C:\projects\xmlformat\uuid\application_a-0000e2csv-22c6-8000-9ba2-011c48011c48_72930.xml
C:\projects\xmlformat\uuid\application_a-0000e2ff-22c6-8000-9ba2-011c48011c48_97397.xml

Destination should be as created as follows

C:\projects\test\output\new.xml
C:\projects\test\output\patches.xml
C:\projects\test\output\application_a-0000e2csv-22c6-8000-9ba2-011c48011c48_72930.xml
C:\projects\test\output\application_a-0000e2ff-22c6-8000-9ba2-011c48011c48_97397.xml

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `ET.parse('f')`. When you feed `parse` a string, it tries to open a file using the string as a file path, so it's literally looking for a file named "f" in the working directory.

You want something like:

```
for f in files:
     ...
     xmlfile  = ET.parse(f)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reponse. Yes i figured out the issue. can you please check the question once again and put any idea which you have regarding the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved, here is the python code which is working fine

```
import os
import lxml.etree as ET

inputpath = "C:\\projects\\test\\uuid\\"
xsltfile = "C:\\projects\\test\\uuid\\uuid.xslt"
outpath = "C:\\projects\\test\\output"

dir = []

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
    structure = os.path.join(outpath, dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    if not os.path.isdir(structure):
        os.mkdir(structure)
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(('.xml')):
            dir = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            print(dir)
            dom = ET.parse(dir)
            xslt = ET.parse(xsltfile)
            transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
            newdom = transform(dom)
            outfile = open(structure + "\\" + filename, 'a')
            outfile.write(ET.tostring(newdom,pretty_print=True).decode())
```